# Need suggestion in printing the matched result one by one by using HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath findnodes() method

Tags: html, xml, perl, xpath, html-treebuilder

I am parsing an html content by using  [HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm) 
in Perl . i have got the xpath location of the data i need. The issue i am facing is ,There are several matches of the xpath `$html->findnodes()`which is returned by single result ,but i need to print it one by one. Need some suggestion .Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over  using

```
  for my $node (@$paraelements)  { ..... }
```

A more complete example

```
  use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
  my $tree= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
  $tree->parse_file( "mypage.html");
  my $paraelements= $tree->findnodes( '//p') ;

  for my $node (@$paraelements)  {
      say $node->as_HTML() ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns a reference to a list (ARRAYREF). To get back the list, put a @ before the variable to tell Perl to treat that as the [location/memory address] of the list just as JIT's sample code